# Submitting form in landing page (cloud pages) using ajax?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ajax, form, landing-page

I have several forms in a Cloud Pages Landing Page.

Using smart capture will not work to submit them since some of the forms are inside list items and the success message needs to be in a list item as well.

In some other case on the same page, the form is in a jquery popup that softly fases in and I want to submit and softly fade out the popup again.

So ajax? Or is that an old solution. Would jquery be better?
Or serverside javascript?

All submitted information should go to a data extension.
It's all just pretty basic stuff. Name and email.

Has anyone done that? Any hints or even code examples would make me so happy.

Thanks in advance